# What's the meaning of the word owing in this context? (Warning! Spoilers for Dostoevsky's Crime And Punishment)

Tags: word-meaning, word-in-context

This is the context from [an English tranlation] (https://etc.usf.edu/lit2go/182/crime-and-punishment/3393/part-1-chapter-2/) of *Crime And Punishment* by Dostoevsky

This is what Mr. Luzhin (a suitor) said to one of the characters in the novel, and what was written in the letter, to the main protagonist Raskolnikov:

> "a man ought not to be indebted to his wife, but that it is better for a wife to look upon her husband as her benefactor"

This is the part describing Raskolnikov's pondering on that statement, after reading the letter:

> "And now mother and she have taken it into their heads that she can put up with Mr. Luzhin, who propounds the theory of the superiority
> of wives raised from destitution and ***owing*** everything to
> their husband’s bounty—who propounds it, too, almost at
> the first interview"

TFD def for the prep "owing to" is:
Because of; on account of: *I couldn't attend, owing to illness*.
But I don't think this is the correct definition for this context because it has the word "everything" in the middle.

Also TFD def for the adj. owing is:
Still to be paid; due.

But none of these fits here. For me "owing" here seems like an adjective in this context.
Also as far as I know "I am owing you something" is incorrect and instead, you should use the "owe" form.

Comment: "<subject> owe <dir-obj> to <ind-obj>" is the structure here.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, *owing* is a [present participle](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/present_participle.htm) being used adjectivally.  More specifically, it's being used in a [participle phrase](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/participle_phrases.htm).

Participial phrases can usually be rephrased by including *who*, which can then turn the present participle into a present progressive verb like this:

Raskolnikov complains about the **man propounding his views** on women
Raskolnikov complains about the **man who is propounding his views** on women.

This works with your example phrase as well, except that we don't use *owe* in the present progressive (as you've correctly noted), so it must be rephrased like this:

Mr. Luzhin prefers **wives owing everything** to their husbands
Mr. Luzhin prefers **wives who owe everything** to their husbands

Now we can see that the meaning of *owing* is the basic meaning of the verb:

> **owe** verb
>
> 2 : to be indebted for
> // *owed* his wealth to his father
> // *owes* much to good luck

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/owe

Or, to rephrase most simply: Mr. Luzhin prefers women who were poor and only have money (and status, etc.) because their husbands gave it to them.

Comment: So then, does this mean we don't use "owe" in the present progressive anymore? Is it just a dated form of writing? If I used it in this way nowadays, would it be considered incorrect?

Comment: @StaticBounce, my answer was probably a bit unclear.  In your example sentence, "owing" is not in the present progressive, it's a present participle.  What I meant to say is that there's some similarity between present progressive and present participle (they both use the -ing forms).  But you are correct that we do not say, "She is owing"; only "She owes."  And this use of the present participle "owing" does sound a little dated.  In fact, much of the sentence sounds dated ("propounds the theory of", "raised from destitution", "husbands' bounty").

Comment: Ok, got it, thank for the effort :)